# Lifting out certain words in SWIFT message

Tags: c#, .net, regex, swift-mt

I have the following regex expression:

```
(?<=[^:]:)?([a-zA-Z]{6}\w[a-zA-Z]{4})
```

Which is looking for every instance of SWIFT BIC code.

The SWIFT code consists of 8 or 11 characters. When 8-digits code is given, it refers to the primary office.

1. First 4 characters - bank code (only letters)
2. Next 2 characters - ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code (only letters)
3. Next 2 characters - location code (letters and digits) (passive participant will have "1" in the second character)
4. Last 3 characters - branch code, optional ('XXX' for primary office) (letters and digits)

So given the list items above and my regex expression, i'm trying to lift out of this exmaple string all the BICS. The screen shot shows, what i'm watching, correctly and wrongly.

[image]

You can see at the top, that i'm not there. I need to only pull back these:

- BARCGB2LXXX
- BARCGB2LXXX
- HSBCGB2LXXX
- HSBCGB2LXXX
- RBOSGB2RTCM
- SABCIR2HXXX

***EDIT***

Perhaps may be best to quantify that this regex is intended to be used within .NET application

Comment: Not possible with regex unless all end with XXX, thankyou !

Comment: is the last fourth character always a digit ? 1 or 2 for passive and active resp .

Comment: @aelor the 4 list points stipulate to constructs of the BIC

Comment: last doubt : is this code always going to be at the end of the string ?

Answer (score 2):

assuming the code to be at the end of every string, this will work:

```
[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}([A-Z0-9]{3})?$
```

[**demo here**](http://regex101.com/r/kN5qN3)

Comment: Ok, so this works in your regex, but not in mine. in Mine it only returns the last BIC SABIR2HXXX.

Comment: have you added the modifiers ? `gm` for `global` and `multiline`

Comment: plus, if there is any text following the optional XXX that they aren't picked up.

Comment: ohhkk :( so there is going to be text after XXX. thats too bad. My answer relies on the code ending at XXX. nyways i ll remove the answer

Comment: Alas yes, i'm trying to pull out from anywhere. Keep your answer, though as i'll mark up as i can use this method elsewhere.

Comment: If you remove the $ from the end, it should match that pattern even if the string doesn't end there.

Comment: yes it will match, thats what I dont want to happen